# PHP 5.3 class as object - confused

Tags: php, apache, iis-6

I'm trying to get a PHP 5.3 legacy website to run on my local machine and may be confused about syntax because I'm not familiar with OOP or PHP.  There is a line of code that I think is supposed to create a class out of an array:

```
$page = ContentPage::getPage($site['id'], $url);
```

where $site is an array containing an id property and $url is 'index.php'

On the live site, this works but on my local machine I get a

```
Notice:Trying to get property of non-object
```

On that $page constructor line.  I'm running PHP 5.3.1 on my machine with Apache, and although the live site is running Windows server IIS 6.0 it's my understanding that this shouldn't affect my ability to run it on wamp?

Forgive me, I've never worked with this older PHP and wonder if I may be missing something basic about syntax?  Thank you

**EDIT:  Adding Getpage Method**

```
static function getPage($site_id = 0, $url = '', $data = true){

    if(!$site_id || !$url){
        return false;
    }

    $url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);

    if(!is_numeric($url)){
        $url = "content_revision.url = '$url' ";
    } else {
        $url = "content_page.id = $url ";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT content_revision.*, content_template.machine_name AS template_name, content_template.id AS content_template_id,
                    content_page.is_sold,
                    content_page.new_home as new_home,
                    content_page.css_classes,
                    site.domain, site.name as site_name, site.id as site_id,
                    site.facebook_url,
                    site.google_url,
                    site.houzz_url,
                    site.blogspot_url,
                    site.youtube_url,
                    site.hours AS site_hours, site.telephone AS site_telephone, site.toll_free_telephone AS site_toll_free_telephone,
                    site.analytics as site_analytics,
                    site.machine_name as site_machine_name,
                IF(content_revision.id IS NOT NULL, CONCAT_WS('/', site.domain, content_revision.url), '') AS `path`
            FROM content_page
            LEFT JOIN content_revision ON content_revision.id = content_page.publish_content_revision_id
            LEFT JOIN content_template ON content_template.id = content_page.content_template_id
            LEFT JOIN site ON site.id = content_page.site_id
            WHERE $url AND content_page.site_id = $site_id";

    $page = db_query_array($sql,'',true);

    // echo "<!--\n";
    // print_r($page);
    // echo "-->";

    if(!$page)
        return false;

    if($data)
        $data = ContentRevision::getData($page['id'], $page['content_template_id']);
    else
        $data = false;

    return array(
        'meta' => $page,
        'data' => $data,
        );
}
```

Comment: You'll need to supply the code for the `getPage()` method, Your issue resides inside it

Comment: So suppling a backtrace should help too

Comment: Thanks I supplied the getPage method and will start backtrace